# How to show validation state of ng-select?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-ngselect

Here's a sample [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmhzr9)

I am using ng-select and want to change border-color whether the validation is error or not.

Been doing this for hours. docs is not that clear it only shows scss syntax not the html one

Comment: Check the docs it's right there: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#validation-state

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same by making the following changes :

**component.ts**

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,  // add this line
})
```

**component.scss**

```
.ng-select.ng-select-opened>.ng-select-container   {
  border-color: #3bff44 !important;
}

.ng-select .ng-select-container{
      border: 1px solid #3bff44;
}

.ng-select.ng-select-focused:not(.ng-select-opened)>.ng-select-container { border: 1px solid #3bff44;}
```

here is working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3p8z8u

Comment: how is the demo "working" ? The borders stay green when I click the "turn red" button : https://imgur.com/Xq3Cw4c

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that there is a syntax error when you are creating the form. To correctly initialize the `inputBaseUnit` formControl as a `required` field, use the below syntax.

```js
this.itemForm = this.fb.group({ 
    inputBaseUnit: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
```

where `''` is the initial value of your `ng-select`

Since you have only one `Validator`, you can shorten the above code like so

```js
this.itemForm = this.fb.group({ 
    inputBaseUnit: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Now if you touch your select and click outside, you will see the yellow border you added in your css.